# Implementing TDD midway through a project

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am currently at about the 50% point in a web app's development, getting to this point by rapidly coding followed by refactoring. After reviewing with the client again at this point, the scope of the project required for completion is clear and unlikely to change.

Is it advised at this point to start implementing tests? If so, do I create tests for the functionality already completed or prioritize TDD for the remaining parts of the application?

Comment: Cover with tests new functionality and anything you refactor/fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @zerkms it is usually advisable to use TDD for new functionality, and when you change existing behaviour.

To guard the functionality you currently have, use some [integration tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) and [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing) for some typical, and crucial scenarios. Don't aim to achieve high coverage with these tests, as it will be to much of a burden to maintain them in the future. If you will be persistent at writing unit tests for discovered bugs and new stuff in time you will get high coverage.